# Python 3, imp.reload does not appear to have any effect

Tags: python-3.x, ipython

I am modifying a module which contains a class in it.

When I %run another module that uses the mofified class from IPython, the changes do not seem to take effect unless I restart IPython.

I have tried to use imp.reload, but this does not help.  For example, I have put the following the code at the top of my module, but it does not appear to be using the updated version of my modified class (BigMySQLDatabaseGetter in the big_mysql_database_getter module)

```
import imp
import sys
from big_mysql_database_getter import BigMySQLDatabaseGetter
module_big_mysql_database_getter = sys.modules['big_mysql_database_getter']
imp.reload(module_big_mysql_database_getter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Reloading a module doesn't automatically update all references that were created before, it just redefines everything within the module.

So if you do something like:

```
from spam import eggs
imp.reload(spam)
print(spam.eggs is eggs)
```

you'll get `False`, as `eggs` still references the old class. Likewise, instances created before the reload are instances of the old class, not of the new class:

```
import spam
e = spam.eggs()
imp.reload(spam)
print(isinstance(e, spam.eggs))  # False!
```

In your case, you can either reimport `BigMySQLDatabaseGetter` after reloading the module, or instead of directly importing the class just import the module and use `big_mysql_database_getter.BigMySQLDatabaseGetter` instead.